# How to grant EJB roles only to certain entities

Tags: java, permissions, ejb, roles, user-roles

We're building a Java web application. We're using EJB containers and JPA with Wildfly 9.2.

Now we want to integrate a permission system in which a user has a certain role, but this role is only granted in combination with a certain entity. I'll name this access resource Department.

So we would have a list of permission for the user stored in such a table:

```
| User ID | Department | Role    |
| ------- | ---------- | ------- |
| 1       | A          | MANAGER |
| 1       | B          | ADMIN   |
| 2       | B          | MANAGER |
```

In addition we have global roles. A user has a set of global roles that will be applied should there not be an entry in the table above with the deparment in question.

```
| User ID | Role    |
| ------- | ------- |
| 1       | VIEWER  |
| 3       | MANAGER |
```

How can we easily check if a user is in a certain role, given a department?

By just using the annotation @RolesAllowed we can check for a certain role, but not restricted to a department.

Comment: How about a filter?  Given a URL, is it known which department(s) would be accessed by that URL?  If the user is not in those department(s) then deny the request.  Whatever the solution, what happens when there is a re-organization and the departments change?

Comment: Or possibly Interceptors on the EJB tier.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. We certainly looked into that.
We're currently also looking into Apache Shiro. This might satisfy our requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out EJB does not have the features we wanted.
We migrated to Apache Shiro Security and are super happy with it.

Resource based permissions always have to be checked programmatically. Static role and permission based checks can be annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that enterprise java security roles are about *authorization*.

So, you could model the department as a role in your security system as well. It's quite OK for a user to be assigned more than one security role.

Therefore, given a manager in department B:

```
@RolesAllowed({"manager", "B"}
public void someBusinessMethod(...) {
     ...
}
```

Only users who are managers and in department B are *authorized* to invoke this method.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but our departments are dynamic. So we cannot hard code them into our annotations.